# when will runnable executed in message queue?

Tags: android

I know that the handler.post() method, Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue. The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached.

But my question is that i have used runtimer() inside the onCreate() method does the runnable in the message queue is executed after the completion of onCreate() method or when??

```
 public class Stopwatch extends Activity  {
private int seconds;
private boolean Running;
private boolean wasrunning;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stopwatch);
 if (savedInstanceState != null){
    seconds = savedInstanceState.getInt("seconds");
    Running = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("running");
    wasrunning = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("wasrunning");
}
    runtimer();
}

public void start(View v)
{
    Running=true;
    wasrunning= true;
}
public void stop(View v)
{
    wasrunning=false;
 Running=false;
}

public void reset(View v){
seconds=0;
Running= false;
    wasrunning=false;
}

void runtimer(){
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
final Handler h = new Handler();
h.post( new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run() {
    int hour = seconds / 3600;
    int minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60;
    int sec = seconds % 60;
    String time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minutes, sec);
    tv.setText(time);
    if (Running) {
        seconds++;
    }
    h.postDelayed(this,1000);
}
});
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    savedInstanceState.putInt("seconds",seconds);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("Running",Running);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("wasrunning",wasrunning);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does the runnable in the message queue is executed after the completion of onCreate() method

It will be sometime after the `onCreate()` method returns. Exactly when will depend on what else is in the main application thread's message queue and how long that takes.

Comment: if it will run before the onCreate() in my example above , will it not create an endless loop and will restrict the onCreate() to complete??

Comment: @gourav: "if it will run before the onCreate() in my example above" -- it will not. As I wrote, it will run sometime after the `onCreate()` method returns.

Comment: ohh i got it i just misunderstood that,thanks @CommonsWare

Comment: does the runnables always run after the method in which they are posted??

Comment: @gourav: If the method is being called on the same thread that the `Runnable` will run on, yes. `onCreate()` is called on the main application thread. Your use of the `Handler` will result in the `Runnable` being called on the main application thread. That thread can only do one thing at a time. Since you are inside of `onCreate()` when you `post()` the `Runnable`, the `Runnable` will need to wait its turn.

Comment: you mean first it will show the layout and then the runnable instantly changes the TextView ?

Comment: @gourav: How fast "instantly" will be depends on what else is in the main application thread's message queue. I would expect it to be fairly quick, probably in less than a millisecond.

Comment: thank you @commansWare you cleared everything,you were really a great help :)